# Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Array value from mockmvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, parsing, integration-testing, mockmvc

```
public class ModelDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String datasetName;
 
    @JsonRawValue
    private String json;
}
```

Post API is working fine from postman or swagger if I send the following body.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "datasetName": "Insurance",
  "json" : "[{\"ClassName\":\"AAAA\",\"Fields\":[[\"cdsa\",\"csa\"],[\"ca\"]]},{\"ClassName\":\"ca\",\"Fields\":[null]}]"
}
```

But MockMVC test case is giving follwing error in Spring boot project

Bad Request: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('C' (code 67)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('C' (code 67)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 89]

```
mockMvc.perform(post(ENTITY_API_URL).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(ModelDTO))).andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had incorrect Type definition.
e.g.

```
public class ModelDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String datasetName;
 
    private String part;
}
```

So I had to correct it as:

```
public class ModelDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String datasetName;
 
    private List<String> part;
}
```

That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't actually need `@JsonRawValue` so try removing it:

```java
public class ModelDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String datasetName;
    private String json;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g5FFQAY
can you explain this, this link has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

my json were not properly set. it requires backword slash for parsing.
I have added extra two backword slash like '\' and now it is working.

```
private static final String DEFAULT_JSON = "\"[{\\\"ClassName\\\":\\\"Health Aditya Birla\\\",\\\"Fields\\\":[[\\\"Insured Person's Details\\\",\\\"Gender\\\",\\\"Member ID\\\"],[\\\"Policy Details\\\",\\\"Insured Person's Details\\\"],[\\\"Premium Certificate\\\"]]},{\\\"ClassName\\\":\\\"Health Care\\\",\\\"Fields\\\":[[\\\"Details of Insured\\\",\\\"Relationship\\\",\\\"Date Of Birth\\\"],[\\\"Mobile No\\\"],[\\\"Gross Premium\\\",\\\"Goods & Services Tax\\\"]]}]\"";
```

I have referred following link to solve this issue.

[enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g5FFQAY)